# Difference between Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route and Annotation\Route

Tags: symfony, routes, annotations

What is the difference between

`Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route` and `Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route` ?

PHPStorm imported the first automatically when using @Route in the PHPDoc